# Daemon and Service Difference

Tags: linux, windows, service, daemon

What is the difference between daemon and service ? (In windows or Linux).

Comment: My definition (maybe others disagree?) is that a Linux service is specifically a System V-style script located in `/etc/init.d`. A daemon can be any program that runs as a true daemon, i.e. a background process and not attached to any tty.

Comment: The word "daemon" is not commonly used in Windows.

Comment: For a more complete discussion check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612846/what-are-the-behavioral-differences-between-a-daemon-and-a-normal-process
And
https://askubuntu.com/questions/192058/what-is-technical-difference-between-daemon-service-and-process

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A **daemon** is a background, non-interactive program. It is detached from the keyboard and display of any interactive user. The word daemon for denoting a background program is from the Unix culture; it is not universal.

A **service** is a program which responds to requests from other programs over some inter-process communication mechanism (usually over a network). A service is what a server provides. For example, the NFS port mapping service is provided as a separate portmap service, which is implemented as the portmapd daemon.

A service doesn't have to be a daemon, but usually is. A user application with a GUI could have a service built into it: for instance, a file-sharing application.

For more details: https://askubuntu.com/questions/192058/what-is-technical-difference-between-daemon-service-and-process

Comment: "A service doesn't have to be a daemon, but usually is" which means not interactive by the definition "A daemon is a background, non-interactive program". They are not comparable and service can use daemon process as underlying concept to realise its purpose. Hence in Windows services and daemons are interchangeable

Answer (score 8):

Daemons are processes running in the background and are not in your face.They do certain tasks at set times or responds to certain events.

In Windows, daemons are called services.

Comment: At best, your answer is incomplete (i.e. services exist in the Unix and Unix-like realms).

Answer (score 4):

**Daemon**

From wikipedia:

> A daemon is a computer program that runs as a background process,
>   rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user.

For example you want to ping google.com. That means something in your OS should know how to handle the Domain name resolution. That is a daemon.

More to read : [Berkeley Internet Name Daemon (BIND)](https://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/internet/dns/configuration/BIND/)

**Service**

That name comes from Client Server Model. It means that an application runs as a service on a server, and a client version of the application is used to access the service. For example an Apache HTTP server application is a service on a server and a Chrome Browser is a client on a PC.

More to read: [Client Server Model](https://www.inetdaemon.com/tutorials/basic_concepts/client-server.shtml)

Answer (score -2):

A daemon is a computer program that runs as a background process, rather than being under the direct control of an interactive user.
A daemon is a subset of services that always run in memory waiting to service a request.
For example - crond , ftpd ,etc

Whereas, a Service is a server application or set of applications that runs in the background waiting to be used, or carrying out essential task. They are basically called in inter-process communication.
For example - httpd